# RPS capacity of sql azure database

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, testing, azure-sql-database, stress-testing

How can we stress test a Sql Azure database? I want to find out how many requests per second can it handle?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The only way to find out reliably is to write a (very) simple program executing a given SQL workload in a loop. Choose the workload to match your expected production load.

Answer (score 2):

I'd start by reviewing the [Windows Azure SQL Database Performance and Elasticity Guide](http://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/3507.windows-azure-sql-database-performance-and-elasticity-guide.aspx) for all the nuances of throttling.  There are both hard and soft limits on various resources, so there's not really a simple answer here.

You can, of course, hammer your server to see when these limits hit, but since SQL Azure is a shared resource there may be other factors at play.  If you need a specific performance metric that you don't think is reachable with SQL Database, you might investigate the IaaS [Virtual Machine](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsazure/jj156003.aspx) option.